# NDSolve for coupled differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve two first order coupled differential equations for the variables `yD` and `yN` given as,

```
sol1 = 
  NDSolve[
    {{yD'[x] == -((1.81*10^11 (yD[x]^2 - yN[x]^2))/x^2), 
      yN'[x] == -2.35 *10^9 x (yN[x] - 0.0094 E^(-3 x/4) x^(3/2)) + 
        (1.81*10^11 (yD[x]^2 - yN[x]^2))/x^2 - 
        (1.81*10^7 (yN[x]^2 - (0.0094 E^(-3 x/4) x^(3/2))^2))/x^2}, 
     {yD[1] == 0.00107, yN[1] == 0.00445}}, 
    {yD, yN}, {x, 1, 30},
    Method -> {StiffnessSwitching,Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
    MaxSteps -> 50000, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 10,
    PrecisionGoal -> 10]
```

I get an error message

> The precision of the differential equation is less than WorkingPrecision (50.).

Increasing the WorkingPrecision further or using InterpolationOrder -> All does not help.

The plot for the solutions

```
LogLogPlot[
  {Evaluate[yD[x] /. sol1], Evaluate[yN[x] /. sol1],}, {x, 1,30}, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, 1000}, {10^-14, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Orange}]
```

[image: solutions for yD, yN]

shows very wiggling behavior for the `yN[x]` solution, however the `yD[x]` solution is very smooth. Can anyone help me in getting rid of the error message and finding a stable, smooth solution for `yN[x]` also.

Comment: Your use of constants like `1.81*10^11` and `0.0094` run counter against `WorkingPrecision -> 50`; if you must, run `Rationalize[]` or `SetPrecision[]` over these inexact numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Rationalize[ ] worked fine and the error message is gone now. But I still have the same wiggling behavior for yN[x] solution. Is there a problem in numerical interpolation of the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seemed to have a few issues in your code.

1. Your numbers were expressed in machine precision, which prevented the use of higher precision even when `WorkingPrecision` was set. This was pointed out in comments as well.
2. Furthermore, your `Method` directive should have had names of
   methods as strings, rather than as symbols.

Once those are fixed, and the WorkingPrecision increased appropriately, you can get a smooth plot for both functions. In fact, you get *pretty much the same plot*:

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{
    yD'[x] == -((181*10^9 (yD[x]^2 - yN[x]^2))/x^2), 
    yN'[x] == -235*^7 x (yN[x] - 94*^-4 E^(-3 x/4) x^(3/2)) + (181*^9 (yD[x]^2 - yN[x]^2))/
       x^2 - (181*^5 (yN[x]^2 - (94*^-4 E^(-3 x/4) x^(3/2))^2))/x^2,
    yD[1] == 107*^-5, yN[1] == 445*^-5},
   {yD, yN}, {x, 1, 30},
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}},
   WorkingPrecision -> 35
 ];

LogLogPlot[
 Evaluate[{yD[x], yN[x]} /. sol1],
 {x, 1, 30},
 PlotStyle -> {Gray, Orange}, PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]